# Java and Hibernate: OrderBy using HQL and STRING_TO_ARRAY

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql

let´s suppose I have a table with three columns (ID,Description, Sequence) whatever you prefer, and I'd like to order by this string sequence:

```
ID | Description | Sequence
1  | 'Test1'       | '1.8'
2  | 'Test2'       | '1.9'
3  | 'Test3'       | '1.10'
4  | 'Test4'       | '1.3'
```

According to this post ([Ordering dot-delimited numeric sequences (e.g., version numbers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089961/ordering-dot-delimited-numeric-sequences-e-g-version-numbers)), I can use STING_TO_ARRAY('.') as int[] and it works just fine on the DB.

I've tried the following, but I get `unexpected token:` error:

```
(" order by STRING_TO_ARRAY(c.sequence, '.')::Integer[] ");
```

Is it possible to use it in a HQL query?

Comment: `STRING_TO_ARRAY` is a Postgres SQL function, and is not part of the HQL language.   Therefore, you cannot use this function from HQL.  You could, however, use it from a native query.

Comment: If i just write in HQL (" order by STRING_TO_ARRAY(c.sequence)"), I don´t get the error and I'm able to get the generated query on console.. I'm wondering if it's possible to cast it somehow. Thank you @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I'm surprised that even works.  If the version with the cast does not work, then give up and just use a native query.

Comment: Maybe you're right and it is time to give up...